# Python os.walk() function vs. find command

Tags: python, find, os.walk

I am writing a program to walk the filesystem to collect file information to put into a database.  I am trying to learn python after a lifetime of shell scripting, and am seeing an issue between what find returns and what `os.walk` returns

```
find THIS_PATH -print

for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk( THIS_PATH ):
    print ( root )
    for fname in files:
        print ( os.path.join( root, fname ) )
```

The issue I have is that the "OS" `find` returns symlinks to directories, but the python find does not, and I have no idea how to make it do that.  Now I don't want it to follow them (i.e. `followlinks=True`) and that would create a different result from find as well.  But I want to be able to print the entries that are symlinks to directories.

thanks
c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get same output (sorting may vary), you need to print both directories and files for given path. `find` returns directories as well as links (to anything). Minimal change to you code would be:

```
print(THIS_PATH)
for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(THIS_PATH):
    for fname in dirs + files:  # iterate over items form both lists
        print (os.path.join(dirpath, fname))
```

This may be a bit easier to do with [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib):

```
from pathlib import Path
mypath = Path(THIS_PATH)
for found_item in mypath.rglob('*'):
    print(mypath.joinpath(found_item))
```

For instance I've created the following tree:

```
.
├── d1
│   ├── d2
│   │   └── f2
│   └── f1
├── f2 -> d1/d2/f2
└── l1 -> d1
```

Running `find` will yield (note directories and links to directories appear the same way):

```
$ find .
.
./f2
./l1
./d1
./d1/.h
./d1/d2
./d1/d2/f2
./d1/f1
```

And running the first snippet with `THIS_PATH='.'` yields the same items (in slightly different order, `find` would default to depth first, `os.walk` does breadth first). For that `pathlib` example just be ware if `THIS_PATH` is `'.'`, as is it would chomp the leading `./` off.